# Does anyone not agree with the fact that "Gale Bertram was one of the Red John's Man"?

Tags: the-mentalist

I have doubts about **Gale Bertram being one of Red John's men**. The main reason is in the 3rd season, final episode titled "Strawberries and Cream (Part II)".

In this episode the suspects are:

1. Brenda Shettrick, CBI Media Relations
2. Osvaldo 'Oscar' Ardiles, Assistant District Attorney
3. Gale Bertram , CBI Director
4. Craig O'Laughlin of the FBI

Jane also suspects LaRoche, but only Craig O'Laughlin tried to kill Hightower. If Gale Bertram was one of the Red John's men, why didn't he try to kill Hightower?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He wasn't one of Red John's men. He was part of Red John's corrupt organization, As you see in the episode where Jane killed Red John and the episode before that, Bertram is part of that organization and tries to kill Jane because he found out about the organization and some of its members. It is revealed that the three dots tattoo is the seal of the organization and these people have this tattoo: Gale Bertram, Sheriff McAllister and FBI Agent Reede Smith. So you find out that one of these three can be Red John, but just before it's revealed who Red John is, Bertram gets shot by Red John's assailant. So he is not one of Red John's men and he does not know who Red John really is.

Comment: i hope you watched it up to the latest episode so i had not spoiled it for you :)